# How to update a computed field in a rule's "set data a value" action

Tags: rules, entities

I have a custom field called **field_balance** in the user account form which is a **computed field**. It keeps the actual **number of coins** bought by the **current user**. That value is supposed to change (increase or decrease) if the user makes particular manipulations on my **custom content type** which is called **Ads**.

**How do I increase the field's value?** By setting up the field.

[image: Setting on field_balance]

**How do I decrease the value?** I am using **Rules module** to make the field's value decrease. **But it doesn't work well yet**. This is what I have already tried:

- **The Event**: After updating existing content of type Ads
- **The conditions**: User has roles "ad editor"
- **The Action** : Set a data value. **But when I select the field called 
  "site:current-user:field-balance" and hit "Continue", The Data selector turns red and a notification appears**.

Here is the **illustration**:

[image: Add new action screen showing error on data selector]

What is it about the **computed field** that does not continue the rule? Is there any other way to update a computed field with the Rules module?

Comment: Does your computed field allow unlimited values? or only 1 value?

Comment: There is no such think as the number of values on this field type. And my computed field is ment to keep only one value at a time. The calculation (in the field's settings) is always  : "$field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_balance");
$entity_field[0]["value"] = $field_a[0]["value"] + $field_b[0]["value"];". So everytime I add something to the field, the value increases. But when I want to reduce that value (with Rules), that's when things get difficult.

Comment: Do you really need a computed field? Can't you create an integer field instead and change its value with a Rule every time the entity changes?

Comment: I did that. But an integer field will be visible by default when a computed field is just like a variable (so only visible when you need to display it's value).

Comment: I did try that and try to hide it with the help of conditional_fields (the module). But if hidden in the form, it will also be hidden in the display page.

Comment: I would use https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions. You can allow users to see the field, but don't give them access to edit it.

Comment: @Jeroen this can be a good idea to try too. I am now trying to change my computed field to a dynamic field. So I am learning more about Display Suite Dynamic fields to see if this can solve the problem. If not I will turn to your idea.

Comment: @Jeroen. Finally I had some other problems yesterday with Display Suite (Fields not showing in manage display). So I then turned to drupal.org/project/field_permissions. It really helped me do the things quite exactly as I wanted to do them with the computed field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot answer your question directly, so I will propose a solution without computed fields for your specific situation. Since your computed field is just a sum of two other fields, it is perhaps easier to replace it with an ordinary integer field *Balance* and update its value with a simple Rule every time the entity in question changes. In order to allow users to see the field *Balance*, but deny them access to edit it, you can use the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.